# How to compute the Hessian Matrix

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to compute the Hessian matrix of a 2-dimensional vector function.

\begin{pmatrix}x_1 + x_2 + x_3\\x_2^2 -x_1x_2\end{pmatrix}

Can anyone pleae explain how to compute this since I can find it nowhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hessian matrix of a vector function is a $(1,2)$ tensor whose entries are given by $\partial_{i}\partial_{j}f^{k}$. Now i'll let you do the rest, Sjoerd, my friend.

Think of this as two matrices, each one the hessian of a scalar function $f^{1}$ or $f^{2}$. How would you compute the hessian of $f^{1}$? well $f^{1}$ is a first order function, so all the second derivatives are done for, $\partial_{i}\partial_{j}f^{1}=0$, now onto $f^{2}$ the only nonvanishing entries are $\partial_{2}\partial_{2}f^{2}$=$\partial_{2}\partial_{2}x_{2}^{2}$=2 and the mixed $\partial_{2}\partial_{1}f^{2}$=1. Of course the hessian is symmetric, so $\partial_{1}\partial_{2}f^{2}$=1. These are all the nonvanishing entries; just 3.

Comment: Peter,my friend, you are too kind, I will give you the honor to do the rest.. Please

Comment: Thank you, can you then please show me what the final tensor will be?

Comment: Sjoerd, A tensor is specified by it's entries. In this case I cannot give you a nice closed form expression; if you would like draw two hessians, that might help you, but for general tensors this kind of answer is the best you can do.